# Xamarin Studio mac error

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

When I try to build an app (no matter which one) Xamarin throws the next error:

```
Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is 
provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users 
may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's 
expiration date (2046-10-17) or after any future revocation date.
```

Comment: That is just a **warning** and can be ignored for for debug builds...

Comment: yes I know, but it crashes my proyect "Unfortunetely your app has stoped"

Comment: That warning would not cause a crash... review the managed and native stack trace...

Comment: @GustavoSerna Maybe this link help https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/platform-features/advanced-topics/dealing-with-startup-crashes/

Comment: If build is failing, you can check the [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) for potential causes.